# JQuery autocomplete works for one section but not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to get a JQuery function to pick up specific changes to a form and then plug the information into equations so that each section of the form has answers created for it automatically. I got the first part of it to work (Quantity for Posts) but can't get the second part to work (Quantity for Rails). If anyone can point out or explain where I went wrong and how I could fix it it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/ncn42/1/

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div name="inputFence" class="inputFence">
        <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Footage:
            <input name="footage_1" class="footage" />
        </label>
        <select name="fenceHeight_1" class="fenceHeight">
            <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
            <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
            <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
        </select>
        <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Post Quantity:
            <input name="postQuantity_1" class="postQuantity" />
        </label>
        <legend><strong>Rail Type</strong>
        </legend>
        <select name="6foc_1" class="6foc">
            <option value="select">6 Ft. on Center?</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        </select>
        <label>Quantity:
            <input class="railQuantity" name="railQuantity_1" />
        </label>
</fieldset>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//Quantity for Posts
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"] ', function () {

    var footage = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);
    var total = '';
    var parts = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
    var fenceNumber = parts[1];

    if (!isNaN(footage)) {
        total = Math.ceil(footage / 7);
        $(":input[name='postQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val(total.toString());
    } else {
        $(":input[name='postQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val("");
    }

});

//Quantity for Rails
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"] [class^="fenceHeight"] [class^="6foc"]', function () {

    var parts = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
    var fenceNumber = parts[1];

    var footage = parseFloat($(":input[name='footage_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val(), 10);
    var fenceHeight = $(":input[name='fenceHeight_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();
    var railQuantity = $(":input[name='railQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();
    var total = '';
    var sfoc = $(":input[name='6foc_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();

    if (fenceHeight = !NaN) {
        if (sfoc == "no") {

            if (fenceHeight == '8') {
                total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 4);
            }
            if (fenceHeight == '6') {
                total = (Math.ceil(footage / 8) * 3);
            }
            railQuantity.val(total);
        }

        if (sfoc == "yes") {
            if (fenceHeight == '8') {
                total = (Math.ceil(footage / 12) * 4);
                railQuantity.val(total);
            }
            if (fenceHeight == '6') {
                alert("Error: 6ft on Center cannot use 6ft posts");
                railQuantity.val("ERROR");
            }
        }
    } else {
        railQuantity.val("");
    }

});

//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
$('#btnAddFence').click(function () {

    // create the new element via clone()
    var newElem = $('.inputFence:last').clone();

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
    $('.inputFence:last').after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');

    //get the input name and split into array (assuming your clone is always last)
    var parts = $('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name').split("_");
    //change the second element of the array to be one higher
    parts[1]++;
    //join back into a string and apply to the new element
    $('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    //do the same for other two inputs
    parts = $('.postQuantity:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.postQuantity:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    parts = $('.footage:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.footage:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

    parts = $('.6foc:last').attr('name').split("_");
    parts[1]++;
    $('.6foc:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));

});

$('#btnDelFence').click(function () {
    //remove the last inputFence
    $('.inputFence:last').remove();

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if ($('.inputFence').length == 1) $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few problems.

First was this line:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"] [class^="fenceHeight"] [class^="6foc"]',
```

You have to separate the different inputs with a comma as shown here:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"],[class^="fenceHeight"],[class^="6foc"]',
```

Second was this line:

```
var fenceHeight = $(":input[name='fenceHeight_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();
```

You're getting the value of the select, when really you want the value of the selected option:

```
var fenceHeight = $(":input[name='fenceHeight_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val();
```

Third was this line:

```
var railQuantity = $(":input[name='railQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();
```

You're getting the value of this line, when down in the code you're actually trying to set the value *of the value*. What you want is just the element. I've left the quantity in there in case you want that later, but repurposed `railQuantity`:

```
var railQuantity = $(":input[name='railQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']');
var railQuantityval = $(":input[name='railQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val();
```

Fourth is your if statement:

```
if (fenceHeight = !NaN) {
```

You can't really use it like that. Use this instead:

```
if (!isNaN(Number(fenceHeight))) {
```

Down in the if statement, you also could benefit from if/else statements instead of just if statements. I've changed those to reflect this.

You were also missing the railsQuantity element in your add function, which I added for you:

```
parts = $('.railQuantity:last').attr('name').split("_");
parts[1]++;
$('.railQuantity:last').attr('name', parts.join("_"));
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ncn42/5/)

Comment: ...You sir, are my hero. Lol. Thanks.